# How to use a TF-IDF model to find "missing" or under-represented words from a document?

Tags: python, nlp, data-science, gensim, tf-idf

I'm specifically using `gensim` to build a `TfidfModel` but I believe this is more of a general TF-IDF question...

Let's say I build a TF-IDF model with 10 documents. How can I use this model to detect words that are high-value in the model, but under-represented from a specific seen or unseen document?

For example, if documents 1-9 all use the word "banana" frequently, how can I discover that document 10 (or a document not used to build the model) doesn't use it at all?

I know that I could just pull a dictionary of words and values from the model and do my own kind of comparison but I'm wondering if there's a better way.

Comment: Are you only wanting to detect single missing word? Or is it a more general “not relevant” detector? Asking because I’d think for single words I’d scan the documents manually for the hot topics. But if more complex/general then large cosine distances or other stats might be better.

Comment: For my use case, all of the documents would be pretty similar. So my desire would be to have a model that I could pass a new document into and have it say "based on the documents this model was built on, this new document does not mention X, Y or Z as frequently"

I'm thinking some sort of manual scan and comparison is the way to go.

Comment: Then it sounds you are looking for a inverse similarity matcher - the opposite of a search engine, e.g. selecting the documents with the largest cosine distance. I will write up a gensim specific answer when I get a moment, but I think it should be easy.